# Building android source code

Tags: android, c++, android-intent

I downloaded android source from source.android.com and followed the instruction to setup build environment on MAC OS X, Everything went fine except when i run make it gives me following error

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=ITL41D
============================================
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp:2161:38: warning: unused parameter 'bundle' [-Wunused-parameter]
AaptAssets::slurpResourceZip(Bundle* bundle, const char* filename)
                                     ^
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp:5:
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.h:10:
In file included from frameworks/base/include/utils/AssetManager.h:25:
frameworks/base/include/utils/KeyedVector.h:193:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'indexOfKey'
    ssize_t i = indexOfKey(key);
                ^
                this->
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.h:446:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'android::DefaultKeyedVector<android::String8, android::sp<AaptSymbols> >::valueFor' requested here
        sp<AaptSymbols> sym = mNestedSymbols.valueFor(name);
                                             ^
frameworks/base/include/utils/KeyedVector.h:66:29: note: must qualify identifier to find this declaration in dependent base class
            ssize_t         indexOfKey(const KEY& key) const;
                            ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/AaptAssets.o] Error 1
```

I just started in android so do not have any clue, any small help also would be appreciated

Comment: What commands did you run before starting the compiler ?

Comment: source build/envsetup.sh then lunch full-eng and then make-j4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem.
There's an error in the sourcecode of frameworks/base/include/utils/KeyedVector.h:193

Some of the member functions require Scope resolution operator "this->" to build the android source on MAC OS X Lion with xcode 4.3.x and on gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10).
Without scope resolution operator compiler will not be able to identify the existence of the function.

Open frameworks/base/include/utils/KeyedVector.h

Change the line 193 from:

```
ssize_t i = indexOfKey(key);
```

to

```
ssize_t i = this->indexOfKey(key);
```

and Android 4.0.1 compiles.

Comment: What does this mean? Please give further instructions so it can help the rest of us

Comment: There's an error in the sourcecode:
of `frameworks/base/include/utils/KeyedVector.h` Line 193
that occurs AT LEAST with gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10).

Change the line there from:

`ssize_t i = indexOfKey(key);`

to `ssize_t i = this->indexOfKey(key);`

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on Pete's answer, in case anyone really wants to know:

The indexOfKey is defined in DefaultKeyVector's parent class, KeyedVector.  For class templates, a function call is resolved during compile-time, not during run-time.  The error happens because at the point indexOfKey is called, the compiler wouldn't know where that template function might be located.  Here is how the base and derived classes look like:

```
template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class KeyedVector
{
...
    ssize_t indexOfKey(const KEY& key) const;
...


template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class DefaultKeyedVector : public KeyedVector<KEY, VALUE>
{
...
```

And the offending call:

```
template<typename KEY, typename VALUE> inline
const VALUE& DefaultKeyedVector<KEY,VALUE>::valueFor(const KEY& key) const {
    ssize_t i = indexOfKey(key);
...
```

Most likely, using the older MacOS SDK compiler (or other compilers) works because it was probably just guessing the function exists in some base class, instead of failing.  However, that is not standard behavior.

More info from this [clang entry](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup_bases), and from the [C++ FAQ](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#base-lookup).

Answer (score 0):

To build ICS on newer GCC versions, you must apply these patches:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/2EwtWQTqjdI/fbZlzXErscwJ

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem several times when building Browser for Android 4.0.3 with make -j Browser on MAC OS X  10.8.4. I dont have any problem with Android 4.2.1. 
So my solution is

`make CC=gcc CXX=g++ -j Browser`

Hope it helps