# Error in Android KeyedVector.h file

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building android source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171897/building-android-source-code)

I am getting the following error while building Android source code on OS X 10.7.3:

> frameworks/base/include/utils/KeyedVector.h:193:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'indexOfKey'
>   ssize_t i = indexOfKey(key);

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem.

Some of the member functions require Scope resolution operator "this->" to build the android source on MAC OS X Lion with xcode 4.3.x, without scope resolution operator compiler will not be able to identify the existence of the function